# How to enable packages from older ubuntu releases?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, apt, dependencies

There's a time I'm wanting to enable MSN with empathy (as you can see on my other question [Connecting Empathy to  Windows Live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125813/did-empathy-lose-support-to-windows-live-in-12-04/130239#130239)) but I always get problems with dependencies while installing packages.  For instance, I want to install the package `telepathy-haze`, but it depends on the package  `libpurple0`. Ok, but when I try to `sudo apt-get install libpurple0` it says I got unmet dependencies: it depends upon `libgstfarsight0.10-0 (>= 0.0.3)`, `libperl5.12 (>= 5.12.4)`, and `perlapi-5.12.4`, all of them cannot be installed. When I search for these packages at http://packages.ubuntu.com, I can only find them as Oneiric packages, not as Precise. How can I install packages from older releases, such as Oneiric, and solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download all the debs you need and use `dpkg` to install the files one by one.

dpkg does not check for dependencies so you can hose your system so plan it carefully.

edit: Looks like `libgstfarsight` got replaced with package `farstream`

So you need to install libgstfarsight0.10-0 (>= 0.0.3), libperl5.12 (>= 5.12.4), and perlapi-5.12.4 with dpkg and you should then be able to install telepathy-haze (libpurple will install itself)

Another option:

Tarball with source can be found here with a newest version created 2012.04 (so it is very recent): http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/releases/telepathy-haze/

Looks like this one depends on telepathy-glib ≥ 0.13.9 and libpurple ≥ 2.7.0.

Comment: 2012 and we still have to download .deb dependencies? D:

Comment: abadoned? D: I thought the mantainers of the repos kinda forgot to put the packages on precise.

Comment: farstream doesn't exist :/ http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=farstream I already have libtelepathy-farstream2 but it seems that is doesn't suffice D: I guess I'll stay with emesene for some time more.